# Viewchild return undefined

Tags: angular, anchor

I want use html anchor with child component. I'm trying to use `@ViewChild` but value return undefined. Can you helping me ?

My headerComponent :

```
//My html
<button (click)="scrollToElement(target)"></button>

//My TS
@ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target;

scrollToElement($element): void {
  console.log($element);
  $element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
}
```

My homeComponent ( used to centralize all components )

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-anchor></app-anchor>
```

My AnchorComponent :

```
<div #target>My target</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to reach the div element in AnchorComponent? and you want it in the HeaderComponent?

Comment: Yes,  my main menu is in headerComponent and I want reach the div in AnchorComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for communicating between sibling components:

You must call the @ViewChild only in the TS file of the same component,
and not in a different component.

So, in the HomeComponent template, we put an id (`#anchor`) in the `<app-anchor>`, 
then we bind it to the HeaderComponent @Input member.

Now you can access to all AnchorComponent members in the HeaderComponent.

**Solution** -

**HomeComponent**

```
<app-header [anchorComponent]="anchor"></app-header>
<app-anchor #anchor></app-anchor>
```

**HeaderComponent**:

TS:

```
@input() anchorComponent:AnchorComponent ;

scrollToElement(): void {
  //This is how to reach to your div#target
  console.log(this.anchorComponent.target);
  ...
}
```

**AnchorComponent**

HTML:

```
<div #target>My target</div>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target;
```